# TexMaker + Sumatra PDF Forward search

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I am trying to configure TexMaker with SumatraPDF.

This has previously been discussed
[Configure forward search with Texmaker + SumatraPDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/configure-forward-search-with-texmaker-sumatrapdf)
but the solutions did not work for me.

Under "Options >> Configure TexMaker >> Commands >> PDF viewer", I have entered the following

```bsh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe"  -invert-colors -reuse-instance "%.pdf" -reuse-instance -forward-search "%.tex" @
```

This "almost works".  When I build and view the output, I get two PDFs.  One PDF is the document I wish to view.  This PDF also has the correct source links so I can do an inverse search from sumatra.  But SumatraPDF also tries to the same PDF file, but from the following location:

```
C:\users\mattlorig\documents
```

which is not where the document is located.

Also, I use the `-invert-colors` option so that I get a black PDF with white letters.

Comment: FYI, I know I have put -reuse-instance twice.  This appears to be the only way to get the forward search and inverse search to work properly.

Comment: Texniccenter is my default LaTex Editor.  But, I don't see why that should make a difference.  I am compiling the TeX document from TexMaker

Versions:

Comment: versions: sumatra 2.2.1, TexMaker 3.5.2, MikTex 2.9

Comment: Sorry.  Adding another "%.pdf" after the second -reuse-instance did not work.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Also, if the path was not correct, I would assume that I would not open the PDF file in one instance correctly.

Comment: @user26807 Did you see the [issue tracker of TeXmaker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=420&can=1&q=sumatra&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary) ?

Comment: @user26807 Tick the button 'options-->configure-->QuickBuild-->' `Don't launch a new instance of viewer if the dvi/ps/pdf already opened`

Comment: I have checked the corresponding box.  It does not appear to help.

Comment: The following works: "C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -invert-colors -reuse-instance "#.pdf" -forward-search "#.tex" @ I guess I had to change: ? ---> # .

Comment: it's mentioned already in [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=420#c6). If it works, you should add it as a comment to [first original thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/configure-forward-search-with-texmaker-sumatrapdf) with help of some moderator and make this thread as duplicate to tidy up the forum.

Comment: issue 420 was deleted (why??), but you can see it in the web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130610162215/http://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=420

Comment: UPDATE NOTE 2019 there is NO general reason for any reuse-instance (it's for DDE which is depreciated) the editor should not attempt to call it the preferred syntax call is a variant of  -forward-search file.tex line file.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's much of a comment rather than a full pledged answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37535/15717) by Matth

1. Double use of `-reuse-instance` was not needed to resolve your problem
2. Starting from [Version 3.2.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html)
   "- an additional parameter (`#`) for the current file name is available for the commands (required for pdf synchronization with the sumatra pdf viewer)"
3. You have missed `#` it your command line arguments, which was mentioned by [Matth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37535/15717)

   ```
   "C:/Programme/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance "%.pdf" -forward-search "#.tex" @
   ```
4. Hence forward-inverse search works when you remove multiple `-reuse-instance`  and replace the `%` to `#`

**Note:** `%` is for filename without extension. For forward-inverse interaction `#` takes over the precedence. Both might work along as `#` is used for `#.tex`.

Comment: UPDATE NOTE 2019 there is NO general reason for any reuse-instance (it's for DDE which is depreciated) the editor should not attempt to call it the preferred syntax call is a variant of  -forward-search file.tex line file.pdf