# Problem with TexMaker and Sumatra PDF

Tags: texmaker

When I do quick build with Texmaker, it is also trying to open the output file from desktop and giving

```
error loading C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\pdfname.pdf
```

error. But it is also opening original file thus producing two output files for same tex file (one with error). I configured Texmaker as mentioned in the following link: [Configure forward search with Texmaker + SumatraPDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/configure-forward-search-with-texmaker-sumatrapdf) (I used first and third solutions. Both gave the same error.)

What am I missing?

EDIT:- Now I got the issue. If another pdf file is opened(say 'some.pdf' file on the desktop), then sumatra is trying to open newly built pdf from desktop. That's why I am getting the error.

How to rectify this weird behavior?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Did you see similar symptoms solved at [TexMaker + Sumatra PDF Forward search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100774/15717)

Comment: Yes I followed the same steps given in above link but still problem is there. I think problem is with configuring with forward-search only. When I don't add forward search, it is working fine.

Comment: I found out that, we can't use -reuse-instance and -forward-search together because if i use either of them it worked fine. But with both of these, it is giving above error. Looking forward to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by doing a bit of research in the commands.
Actually you have to type following command while using sumatra and texmaker in the path to pdf viewer. Here "!" indicates current directory.

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe " -reuse-instance   "!\%.pdf"  -forward-search  #.tex @
```

Comment: [`!` is an additionnal parameter  for the current directory is available for the commands from 3.3.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) and are you missing doube quotes in "#.tex" ?

Comment: `!` is valid [when \include files are residing in subfolders as discussed by Dany](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=420#c7)

Comment: I didn't use \include command. And i think no need to put double quotes.