# Click on the output of the tex file

Tags: forward-inverse-search, output, terminal-output

When i click on the output of the my Tex file, instead of opens in the my Tex file, It opens in a notepad file. I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.
[image]

I find the following option in the PDF viewer. How can i modify it to open link in the my Tex file. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably, your pdf viewer is not well configured. Which is it, and which is you TeX editor (looks like TeXmaker)?

Comment: What's a "tet file"?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your favor. It is bidiTeXmaker-2013, is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You didn't tell about your pdf viewer. Is it the integrated viewer of TeXmaker, or an external viewer?

Comment: @Bernard it is integrated viewer of TeXmaker. It;s name is SmartaPDF.

Comment: @Bernard I edit my question. Please see the second picture. Thanks.

Comment: ??? Are you sure it's not `SumatraPDF`?

Comment: I edit my question But it needs to peer reviewed. In this new edit you can find my question obviously. Yahh it is Smartapdf.

Comment: @Amin235 It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your advise. I will merge it.

Comment: please see this related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/configure-forward-search-with-texmaker-sumatrapdf

Comment: and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100774/texmaker-sumatra-pdf-forward-search

Answer (score 1):

For `inverse search`, open the `SumatraPDF > Settings > Options` popup window and fill the last form with

```
"Path-to-TeXmaker\texmaker.exe" "%f" -line %l
```

as in the image (I have a non-default installation):
[image]