# Texstudio and Texmaker forward and inverse search

Tags: texmaker, texstudio, forward-inverse-search

Do these programs support forward and inverse search (with built in PDF viewer or YAP) for files that have a root file which has many chapter files used with `\include`? I have tried this with no success. I have `-synctex=--1` directive included and I have set the root file as the "Master Document". I am currently using Windows 7, with latest versions of TeXstudio and Texmaker. My TeX program is Miktex 2.9. The main attraction of these programs for me is that I can use them on Windows and Mac. My main tex editor on windows is Winedt and I am very happy with it.

Comment: I use TeXstudio on Linux and it works well, but the argument to pass is `-synctex=1`.

Comment: `-synctex=-1` would also work, I think.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/configure-forward-search-with-texmaker-sumatrapdf

Comment: You should set the your main file as `Options -> Masterdocument`. Specifically in TeXstudio, you can use Ctrl+LeftClick on the source code and in the internal PDF viewer for forwarwd/inverse search. Forward/inverse search also works for Texmaker, but I don't know the details there.

Comment: The difference between `-synctex=1` and `-synctex=-1` is that the latter won't gzip the `.synctex` file. But `-synctex=--1` fails silently.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using file names with blanks, the problem is with TeXstudio and TeXmaker, whose command line is something like (supposing your file is C cè.tex)

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode C cè.tex
```

while the corresponding command line in WinEdt is

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=-1 -interaction=errorstopmode "C cè.tex"
```

so you would have to change TeXstudio command line (in Options -> Configure -> commands) to

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%.tex"
```

Answer (score 2):

I´ve tried all solutions to this problem found in several forums and none worked. Finally I found out that the problem, in my case, was simply that my file had spaces in its name, which seems to be a problem for `synctex`. Hope it helps in your case as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: `synctex` does not work with `file names` which contain spaces or `filénàmes`with accentuated characters. Best practices of [Naming LaTeX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176/15717)

Comment: `@texenthusiast` the problem with `synctex` and file names with blanks has been solved time ago

Comment: @karlkoeller BTW when was it solved ? which release of TeXLive distro year onwards ? Any documentation on it or release notes/changelog ?

Comment: @texenthusiast Unfortunately I can't remember when. And I've not been able to find anything in changelogs...

Comment: @André Thank you.  it helps in my case as well. Thank you.