# The SumatraPDF Inverse-Search for any arbitrary Editor

Tags: miktex, texmaker, texniccenter, winedt, sumatrapdf

I wanna use texmaker+sumatra, winEdt8+sumatra and texnic Center+sumatra together.
I set the SumatraPDF Inverse-Search option on all editors.
But the SumatraPDF Inverse-Search does not work on WinEdt and TexMaker While working on Texnic Center.

TexMaker setting:
[image]

winEdt setting:
[image]

TexnicCenter setting:
[image]

Comment: Here is a detailed manual on how to use `synctex` with Sumatra PDF: http://william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413

Comment: WinEdt and TC already recognizes SumatraPDF. But you need to choose what to do for inverse search.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Angel SumatraPDF doesn't know which editor compiled the document. It only knows which editor it should send the inverse-search request as given in the SumatraPDF configuration. Even if you compile with WinEdt it will call TeXnicCenter if it is setup like that. In other words, they don't know each other, they are connected via SyncTeX

Comment: anybody help me

Comment: It should work nicely by following the link given by Henri Menke. Basically each editor tells Sumatra via the given parameters what it has to do to enable inverse search. When you switch between editors you have to close all running instances of Sumatra.

Answer (score 7):

The Problem is, mentioned in the questions comment, that SumatraPDF is linked to the Latex-Compiler through synctex and doesnt know, which created the resulting PDF.

You can use the inverse-search command through the a commandlineswitch of SumatraPDF:`-inverse-search`. The commands are:

**TeXnicCenter:**

```
-inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TEXCNTR.EXE\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f', '%l')]\""
```

Note the escapecharacters for doublequotes.

**WinEdt:**

```
-inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt\winedt.exe\" \"[Open(|%f|);SelPar(%l,8)]\""
```

Note the escapecharacters for doublequotes.

**TexMaker:**

```
-inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files\Texmaker\texmaker.exe\" \"%f\" -line %l"
```

Note the escapecharacters for doublequotes.

**Explanations**

Most applications use DDE-commands to interact. So does TeXnicCenter and WinEdt. For inverse-search SumatraPDF has to comunicate with the PDF-producing application. In that case you have to say SumatraPDF which application is the PDF-producer to communicate with. This works with the commandlineswitch I mentioned above. By clicking the view button in the LatexIDE you should start SumatraPDF with the correct parameters.

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "PathToPDF" -inverse-search "PathToEditor InverseSearchCommand"
```

Additional you can use `-reuse-instance` to not open a new PDF-window each time. Also its possible to use only the Latexide applications filename instead of the full path, if the Path of the LatexIDE application is in the systems PATH variable.

Inverse search works for TeXnicCenter, because you added the "TeXnicCenter inverse Search DDE command" correct in SumatraPDFs commandline.

In WinEdt you inserted the correct commandlineswitch but no executable to use for the inverse-search. So use the parameter I mentioned above.

In TexMaker you used no comandlineswitch after all. Add the parameter I mentioned above.

*All the informations found in the net: [TeXnicCenter and WinEdt](http://william.famille-blum.org/blog/static.php?page=static081010-000413), [TexMaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84570/36879)*

Comment: Nice explanation, but this doesn't answer the question... How to let SumatraPDF know which editor has been called by? BTW it is WinEdt, not WinEdit.

Comment: @karlkoeller I edited the misspelling of  WinEdt. The answer of the question is that you call the pdfviewer with an additional commandlineswitch which includes the path to the caller. In this case the pdfviewer knows who called and is able to call back. On the other hand its not possible that you open the pdfviewer manually with an pdf and then want to invoke a inverse-search. Theoretically the pdfviewer uses the last used (the last calling) application.
 Additionally its only possible to use inverse-search if you compile the Tex-document for at least one time with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kludge I would try (I didn't): just install SumatraPDF on several locations, each one configured against a different program. If the configuration is stored by directory (and not in the registry or similar) I see no reason why this won't work. Is quite inelegant, but if you don't mind...

Comment: SumatraPDF can support multiple configurations via -appdata command thus you can call one per editor

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment and my is just a small update of what @RoKi0815 wrote:

At least for **WinEdt 9**, the correct inverse search command is

```
-inverse-search "\"%B\winedt.exe\" \"[Open(|%%f|);SelPar(%%l,8)]\""
```

Note the `%B` for WinEdt installation directory, and `%%f` and `%%l` that will become `%f` and `%l` in SumatraPDF to denote the file name that will be opened and source code line that will be highlighted by inverse search (WinEdt would expand the original `%f` to current WinEdt file and `%l` would expand to the current WinEdt line, instead of the line that has been double-clicked in SumatraPDF).

Comment: This has changed in WinEdt 10 and the auto configurator adds the corrected syntax

Answer (score 0):

SumatraPDF has an undocumented setting that allows you to select different advanced settings files for multiple inverse searches. This is most useful for portable configurations but can also be beneficial for normal installed. Simply add -appdata "path to desired settings file" from each editor this replaces the need to -inverse-search ….

Avoid using DDE (its no longer recommended) ONLY use -inverse-search ONCE to set it up (OR switch ONCE between editors, do not call it repeatedly for every compilation) -reuse-instance is not needed (basically its now ignored in tabbed mode)

Most of the answers on this forum for configuring SumatraPDF are now well out of date. Avoid using DDE to SumatraPDF though it is still needed when starting TeXnicCenter from SumatraPDF see the following.

For TeXnicCenter see [Adobe Reader makes TexNicCenter crash - Alternative Sumatra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/adobe-reader-makes-texniccenter-crash-alternative-sumatra/453731?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#453731)

For WinEdt 10 see [How to configure Inverse Search with WinEdt + Okular configuration?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464885/how-to-configure-inverse-search-with-winedt-okular-configuration/464909?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#464909)