# WinEdt 10 forward search disabled with --synctex=1

Tags: pdftex, winedt, sumatrapdf

I recently installed WinEdt 10 and use SumatraPDF.

With SyncTeX switch `--synctex=1` (i.e. specifying `.synctex.gz`), forward search (<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd>) doesn't work.

However, <kbd>Shift+F8</kbd> works fine with `--synctex=-1`.

<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd> also works fine with either SyncTeX switch in WinEdt 7.

Is this a known problem with WinEdt 10, or is there a problem (what?) with my installation?

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125546/the-sumatrapdf-inverse-search-for-any-arbitrary-editor

Comment: @HenriMenke: That question's about inverse search, not forward search. I have no problem with inverse search, whichever SyncTeX switch I use.

Comment: In WinEdt, go to Options -> Execution Modes -> PDF viewer and set "SyncTeX Switch" to `--synctex=1` and "SyncTeX Filetype" to `.synctex.gz`. Then compile again and retry. It should work (it works fine for me, if it doesn't for you, you must have changed something else in WinEdt configuration)

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks. The SyncTeX Filetype was `.synctex`, not `.synctex.gz`. It's a shame it doesn't change automatically when you change the SyncTeX Switch.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Do you want to copy your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When, in Options -> Execution Modes -> PDF Viewer, you change the field "Synctex Switch" to `--synctex=1`, you also have to change the field "SyncTeX Filetype" to `.synctex.gz` otherwise WinEdt will consider the `.synctex` file instead of the right `.synctex.gz` for forward search.

[image]

After doing that, simply recompile your file and forward search (<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd> in WinEdt) will work fine.